# Alternative to Kakfa-connect due to ARM incompability

Tags: macos, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, arm64

I've been using kafka (using the wurstmeister images, but i have also tried to set up the broker and zookeeper using the confluent images and it works) for a while and I am now trying to set up kafka-connect so I can directly load messages from a kafka topic to S3. However, i've been running into several issues. Qemu errors, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at org.eclipse.jetty.http.MimeTypes, etc,  which I have read that it has something to do with lack of ARM support (https://github.com/confluentinc/common-docker/issues/117 and https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/542). I have tried to run the docker compose with platform: linux/amd64, but it still doesn't work.

I was wondering if anyone has any workarounds to make kafka-connect work or if you know any alternatives.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Docker to run Kafka Connect.

- Install Java on your Mac
- Download Kafka
- Run Zookeeper and Kafka (***this*** might have issues with M1 Mac)
- run `bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties`

If you really *need* Docker, you can rebuild images from other sources, [such as mine](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker), which builds from `adoptopenjdk:11-jre` base image, which supports ARM

Comment: You are a kafka life saver. I have just installed kafka and run it without docker and it seems to be working. I run the connect bit to test it, as i've noticed there is a example filestreamsink in config, and tried to write some messages to the topic. But if it was working there should be a file created, right? Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: The FileStreamSink _should_ create a file on its own.

Comment: Actually, if you dont provide it a config value for a file, it just prints to the connect worker standard out (i.e the terminal)

Comment: I finally i was able to make it work. I am sooo grateful for your help! Next stop: s3 connector! Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure if you have encountered this before, but when I've downloaded the s3 connector from confluence, and added that to the plugin.path. But when I add it I get and error saying java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageSinkConnectorConfi. But if I remove the plugin.path to the s3 connector, it goes back to normal. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd use `confluent-hub` command to ensure the plugin is downloaded and setup correctly. That class, specifically comes from https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/StorageSinkConnectorConfig.java